# two itemize in two colums start at same sheet

Tags: beamer, pdftex, itemize, columns

I have a difficulty with the use of overlay specifications (i think). I have two enumerates in two colums. i want that both start at the same moment. If i use both times `<+->` both enumerations start after each other. Exist something simular that both start at once?
I have below my current method but it is more fail prone.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Example sheet}
        Some text here\\
        space between this and first item resize every item
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5 \textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}<+->
                \item A
                \item B
                \item C
                \item D
                \item E
            \end{itemize}
            \column{0.5 \textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<1-> A
                \item<2-> B
                \item<3-> C
                \item<4-> D
                \item<5-> E
            \end{itemize}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional parameter to `[+-]` where you can set the delay. It is for example used when you don't want the first item to show up directly, but it looks like you can set negative values as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Example sheet}
  Some text here\\
  space between this and first item resize every item
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5 \textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+(0)->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.5 \textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+(-5)->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```